# Can all/most python pip packages be installed using pypy3?

Tags: python, pypy

I am able to install the python3 package of forexconnect using:

```
python3 -m pip install forexconnect
```

but when I try to install it for pypy using:

```
pypy3 -m pip install forexconnect
```

I get the following error,

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement forexconnect (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for forexconnect**

I have looked through the pypy documentation and can't work out what I need to do now. Perhaps I need to re-compile/rebuild the library but unfortunately my knowledge of python isn't good enough to understand what is probably quite straight-forward.

Please, does anyone know what is going on here and what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forexeconnect does not release a source tarball, so they must build a binary version for each python version they wish to support and upload that to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/forexconnect/#files). Most packages will release a source tarball and upload that to PyPI, then `pip install` can build the binary package from source. In this case, the package provider (assuming they do not want to release the source) would have to build a version for PyPy, there is nothing `pip` nor PyPy can do.

Comment: Thanks - that's cleared that up for me. I love this website :-)

Answer (score 0):

To see supported versions by pip try

```
pip install forexconnect==0
```

Then you can set specifical version with

```
pip install forexconnect==versionnumber
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question - there was a typo error. The pypy code should have been "pypy3 -m pip install forexconnect". So, basically I can find the version in python pip but not pypy3 pip. Hope, my problem and question is clearer now.