# How would you install python modules/packages so that my script can be run with pypy3 instead of Python3? ImportError: No module named

Tags: pip, python-module, pypy

I have Python3.8 built from source on my Debian 10 Xfce desktop (binaries are not available in Debian repositories). That said, whenever I can, I run my python scripts with pypy3, which I do for the sake of performance.
Now, when I run the following code with pypy3 :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input("What is the address of the  web page in question?")

response = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.title.string)
```

I get from pypy3:

> ImportError: No module named 'requests'

The same script is run by Python3.8 without any problems

I assume that I would have to install the module in a similar way that I did it for Python, that is: sudo pip3.8 install requests.
[Based on my research of a similar problem described on Stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346917/can-all-most-python-pip-packages-be-installed-using-pypy3) I tried:

```
pypy3 -m pip3.8 install requests
```

and got the following from my pypy3:

> Error while finding module specification for 'pip3.8' (ImportError: No >module named 'pip3')

Then I also tried to run:

```
pypy3 -m pip install requests
```

And got the following:

> No module named pip

My pip3.8 works fine for Python3.8, not for my pypy3, though.

How should I look for modules in pypy3. And how should I install them?
Is the problem with installing and importing modules one of the reasons reason for the low usage of pypy3?

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524140/674039) to install pip for pypy3 interpreter (swapping in `pypy3` instead of command `python`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Run this once to install pip itself: `pypy3 -m ensurepip`

The next version of PyPy will improve the error message to describe this command explicitly when you do `pypy3 -m pip` and pip is not installed yet.

Comment: When I run ```pypy3 -m ensurepip``` I get the following error: AssertionError: []

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  Is that the *complete* output, or just the last line of it?

Answer (score -1):

**pypy3**

Enable snaps on Debian and install pypy3

Snaps are applications packaged with all their dependencies to run on all popular Linux distributions from a single build. They update automatically and roll back gracefully.

Snaps are discoverable and installable from the Snap Store, an app store with an audience of millions.

**Enable snapd:**

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install snapd
```

**Install pypy3:**

```
    sudo snap install pypy3 --classic
```

**Normally, the pip and package are installed as follows**

*First of all, you need to install the pip*

Install pip for Python 3

Follow the steps below to install Pip for Python 3 on Debian:

First, update the package list with:

```
   sudo apt update
```

Next, install pip for Python 3 and all of its dependencies by typing:

```
   sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Verify the installation by printing the pip version:

```
   pip3 --version
```

The version number may be different, but it will look something like the one below:

```
   pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

**Pip Usage**

With pip, we can install packages from PyPI, version control, local projects, and from distribution files but in most cases, you will install packages from PyPI.

we want to install a package named croniter, we can do that by issuing the following command:

```
   pip install requests
```

To uninstall a package run:

```
   pip uninstall requests
```